# XML transformation using PHP5 DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am developing an application were I need to transform XML documents that look like this(words.xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE words SYSTEM "words.dtd">
<words>
<word id="word_1">Alfa</word>
<word id="word_2">Beta</word>
<word id="word_3">Gamma</word>
<word id="word_4">Delta</word>
<word id="word_5">Zeta</word>
</words>
```

Using PHP5 and DOM. I would like the result to be (in this case):

```
word_1 = Alfa
```

My PHP code is this:

```
<?php

$xmlHitzakDok = new DOMDocument();

if($xmlHitzakDok->load("words.xml") === FALSE){die('Errorea hitzen xml-a kargatzean');}

$xPath_Hitzak = new DOMXPath($xmlHitzakDok);

$Hurrengo_Hitza = 'word_1';

foreach ($xPath->query('//words/word') AS $item)
{
   if ($item->getAttribute('id') == $Hurrengo_Hitza)
   {
    echo $item->getAttribute('id') . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br />";
   }
}
```

I am getting no results. Which is the problem?

Comment: Is that the code you actually use? Because then the cause is that you use: $xPath->query('//words/word') instead of $xPath_Hitzak->query('//words/word')

Comment: Ok Thanks, my fault, I didnt realised about that, it's working fine now. Thamks @Mircea

Comment: @Mircea: Please add your solution as an answer below so that Haritz can accept it later.

Answer (score 1):

You should use: $xPath->query('//words/word') instead of $xPath_Hitzak->query('//words/word')